# Rails active record where chaining losing scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Model `Food` has scope `expired`:

**Food.rb**

```rb
class Food < ApplicationRecord
  default_scope { where.not(status: 'DELETED') }
  scope :expired, -> { where('exp_date <= ?', DateTime.now) }
  belongs_to :user
end
```

In my controller I'm chaining where conditions to filter foods by user and status:

**query_type.rb**

```rb
def my_listing_connection(filter)
  user = context[:current_user]
  scope = Food.where(user_id: user.id)
  if filter[:status] == 'ARCHIVED'
    # Line 149
    scope = scope.where(
      Food.expired.or(Food.where(status: 'COMPLETED'))
    )
  else
    scope = scope.where(status: filter[:status])
  end
  scope.order(created_at: :desc, id: :desc)
  # LINE 157
  scope
end
```

Here is the rails log:

```
Food Load (2.7ms)  SELECT `foods`.* FROM `foods` WHERE `foods`.`status` !=
'DELETED' 
AND ((exp_date <= '2020-07-02 09:58:16.435609') OR `foods`.`status` = 'COMPLETED')

↳ app/graphql/types/query_type.rb:149

Food Load (1.6ms)  SELECT `foods`.* FROM `foods` WHERE `foods`.`status` != 'DELETED' 
AND `foods`.`user_id` = 1 ORDER BY `foods`.`created_at` DESC, `foods`.`id` DESC
↳ app/graphql/types/query_type.rb:157
```

Why does active records query loses `expired` scope (and a condition) in line 157?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ignored because `where` doesn't expect scopes like that. But you can use [`merge`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#merging-of-scopes) instead. Replace

```
scope = scope.where(
  Food.expired.or(Food.where(status: 'COMPLETED'))
)
```

with

```
scope = scope.merge(Food.expired)
             .or(Food.where(status: 'COMPLETED'))
```

or

```
scope = scope.where(status: 'COMPLETED').or(Food.expired)
```

Comment: If you need to chain `where` further (with `and` or `or` operators), does it generate wrong query?

Comment: That depends on how and in with order your chain `where` conditions (which will always be added with `AND`) and `or` conditions (which will `OR` only the latest condition before afair).

Comment: `where` doesn't expect scopes like that - can please you explain it in more detail? Or any links?

Comment: Just have a look at the [Rails Guide about conditions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions): `where` accepts Strings, Arrays or Hashes, but not scopes.

Comment: When you look closely you see that the output of line 149 is not the whole query the `where(user_id: user.id)` part is missing. That only means Rails internally fired a database request on the added scope trying to make sense but did not actually add the returned value it to the conditions.

Comment: So the log for line 149 is the result for `Food.expired.or(Food.where(status: 'COMPLETED'))`. Returned type is `ActiveRecordRelation` which doesn't make any sense for `where` method.

Comment: Exactly. When you want to understand what exactly is happening inside when passing an unexpected type to `where` and why Rails triggers the database query, then you need to read the source code of Rails.